# How can I create a method that relates a template object with his own template list?

Tags: c++, list, templates

I've been trying to set up a method that can detect a type of class using templates, and then return a list, related to his class.

This is what I have.

```
template <typename T>
list<T>* foundsType(T* t)
{
    string array[5] = {"Medic", "Dept", "Patient", "Form", "Bed"};
    list<T>* types[] = {medics,depts,pacients,forms,beds};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        string obj = typeid(t).name();
        if(obj == array[i])
            return types[i];
    }
}
```

(`medics`, `depts`, `patients`, `forms` and `beds` are private properties of the class this method is being used)

I know the declaration of the array 'types' is incorrect, but I had to try.

Comment: Can you show us how you intend to use this function?

Comment: `typeid(t).name()` is only for debugging purposes suitable. We definitely need more context.

Comment: It is being used in another method that can find an specific object on the list. Like this:   
`template <typename T>
    bool findsObject(T* t){
        list<T>* list = foundsType(t);
        typename list<T>::iterator it;
        for(it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++){
            if(*t == *it)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
`

Comment: It is strange that you have pointers on list instead of list directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use specialization:

```
template <typename T> list<T>* foundsType();

template <> list<Medic>* foundsType<Medic>() { return medics; }
template <> list<Dept>* foundsType<Dept>() { return depts; }
template <> list<Patient>* foundsType<Patient>() { return patients; }
template <> list<Form>* foundsType<Form>() { return forms; }
template <> list<Bed>* foundsType<Bed>() { return beds; }
```

or you may replace your variable by `std::tuple`(since C++11, C++14 for the `get` by type even if it can be written in C++11):

```
std::tuple<std::list<Medic>*,
           std::list<Dept>*,
           std::list<Patient>*,
           std::list<Form>*,
           std::list<Bed>*> lists;

template <typename T> list<T>* foundsType() { return std::get<std::list<T>*>(lists); }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the header file or the .cpp?

Comment: For the first one, declarations (including specializations) *should* go in header, definitions may go in cpp file. The second one is for header. (Except if you only use the function in only one cpp where all may go in cpp file).